# How to create a circular badge with lines as spokes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I need to replicate this look. How would I go about doing so in either Photoshop or Illustrator?

[image: circular badge]

Comment: There is an exact duplicate of this somewhere, but I can't find it. Basically the easiest way is to use a transform effect.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69725/how-to-make-a-circle-with-grid-on-the-outside-ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create one of your spokes inside a circle with no fill or stroke (this is so you can rotate around the center of the circle)

[image: Single spoke with invisible circle]

2. Apply the Transform effect (**Effect → Transform & Distort → Transform...**) with an angle that is a divisor of 360 and enough copies to fill 360 degrees.

[image: Transform effect dialog]

[image: Final outcome]